# Merge two 2D numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to merge two 2D numpy arrays - `using np.concatenate`. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[]]) #empty 2D array for result
a = np.array([[0.0012, 0.032, 0.039, 0.324]])
b = np.array([[1, 0.2, 0.03039, 0.1324]])
arr = np.concatenate(arr, a, axis=0)
arr = np.concatenate(arr, b, axis=0)
print(arr)
```

I also tried:

```
np.concatenate(arr, a, axis=0)
np.concatenate(arr, b, axis=0)
```

Or:

```
arr = np.concatenate(a, b, axis=0)
```

But It throws error at `arr = np.concatenate(arr, a, axis=0)` line. Error: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Any possible solution? 
I want have this result: `arr = np.array([[0.0012, 0.032, 0.039, 0.324], [1, 0.2, 0.03039, 0.1324]])`

Comment: Start off with something like : `arr = np.empty((0,4))` and then concatenate.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: `arr = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)`

Comment: `np.concatenate((arr, a), axis=0)`?

Comment: Check my edit. Still the same.

Comment: The scalar array error is caused by not paying close enough attention to the documentation.  The first argument is a list of arrays.  Second is a scalar, the axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.0012, 0.032, 0.039, 0.324]])
b = np.array([[1, 0.2, 0.03039, 0.1324]])

result = np.concatenate([a, b], axis=0)

print (result)
```

That gives:

```
[[ 0.0012   0.032    0.039    0.324  ]
 [ 1.       0.2      0.03039  0.1324 ]]
```

Comment: Yes, but I need merge more times the 2 arrays:
When I use your solution, I cant do this:
`a = np.array([[0.0012, 0.032, 0.039, 0.324]])
b = np.array([[1, 0.2, 0.03039, 0.1324]])
c = np.array([[2, 0.3, 5, 190]])

arr = np.concatenate([a, b], axis=0)
arr = np.concatenate([arr, c], axis=0)
print(arr)`

Comment: What do you mean more times? You can do [a, b, a, b] etc if you like as you just give a list to be merged?

Comment: The result will be:
`[[1.200e-03 3.200e-02 3.900e-02 3.240e-01]
 [1.000e+00 2.000e-01 3.039e-02 1.324e-01]
 [2.000e+00 3.000e-01 5.000e+00 1.900e+02]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack) and [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack) functions for it. Note, that vstack needs your arrays to have equal x-dimensions.

```
arr = np.hstack([arr, a])
arr = np.vstack([arr, b])
```

If you want to use [concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) function, you should pass the list of arrays as the first argument:

`arr = np.concatenate([arr, b], axis=0)`

This usage needs to have equal x-dimensions too.

You can also use the [block](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy.block) function for complicated concatenation.

Comment: I am used hstack and this is result of printed arr: `[[0.0012  0.032   0.039   0.324   1.      0.2     0.03039 0.1324 ]]`. But I want have it separated: `[[0.0012, 0.032, 0.039, 0.324], [1, 0.2, 0.03039, 0.1324]]`

Comment: hstack joins arrays horizontally, vstack - vertically. If you want to start with an empty array, you should use hstack in the first time. If you start with non-empty array, you don't need hstack.